# Как обрабатывать нажатие клавиш в реальном режиме?

Tags: ассемблер, ос, yasm

Мне нужно обработать нажатие клавиши для загрузчика в реальном режиме

```
colour:
mov ah,0x00  
int 0x16    
cmp ah,0x31
jae next1
jmp colour

next1:
cmp ah,0x36
jle next2
jmp colour

next2:
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al,'Q'
int 0x10
```

В этом отрывке кода , я хочу работать с клавиатурой,поэтому обрабатываю нажатие клавиши с помощью **int 0x16**
С помощью условных переходов реализовал такую конструкцию

```
if(ah>=0x31 && ah<=0x36)
```

Но на экран так и не выводится буква Q. Можете подсказать,где ошибка? Пишу на YASM

Comment: ascii код символа возвращается в регистре AL, а вы проверяете AH

Comment: @Mike, а почему ascii код сохраняется в al , а не туда , куда я указал

Comment: Я говорил про первые 3 строчки. Вы там ничего не указываете. И прерыванию нельзя указать где что сохранять. Есть соглашение, какое прерывание где что возвращает. Функция 0 прерывания 16h возвращает именно в AL

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно заменить `AH` на `AL` в коде проверки. AL после прерывания 0х16 (AH=0x00) содержит в себе код нажатого символа, а AH - скан код BIOS'а или свое прошлое значение.

Вот более подробная информация о прерываниях DOS и BIOS в реальном режиме: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/